# Continue laplace transform of Levy-subordinator analytically to complex numbers with positive real part.

Tags: complex-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

The following is from [here](http://www.association-tremplin.org/sites/default/files/M2-Bertoin-subordinateurs.pdf) part 1.2.

If $\phi$ is the Laplace exponent of a
subordinator, then there exist a unique pair $(k, d)$ of nonnegative real numbers and a
unique measure $\Pi$ on $(0,\infty)$ with $\int_{(0,\infty)} \min(1,x) \Pi (dx)<\infty$ such that for $\lambda \geq 0$

$$ \phi(\lambda)=k+d\lambda + \int_{(0,\infty)} (1-e^{-\lambda x}) \Pi (dx)$$

Later (second page in 8.4 same source) he states that:

The Laplace exponent $\phi$ of a subordinator (a function as above) can be continued analytically on $\mathbb{C}_+$ - I don't really know what that means.
We really would like to use the above function on complex numbers with positive reel part so I assume that is what it means, but how does it work and why?

(I study probability, so I don't really know which kind of math this is, so feel free to tag it correctly if I haven't)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from the fact that, for every real number $x\geqslant0$ and every complex number $z$ with nonnegative real part, 
$$
|1-\mathrm e^{-zx}|\leqslant\min\{2,|z|\cdot x\}.
$$
The upper bound $2$ follows from the fact that $|\mathrm e^{-zx}|\leqslant1$. The upper bound $|z|\cdot x$ follows from the fact that, for every complex number $u$ with nonnegative real part,
$$
1-\mathrm e^{-u}=u\int_0^1\mathrm e^{-tu}\mathrm dt,
$$
and that $|\mathrm e^{-tu}|\leqslant1$ for every $t$ in $(0,1)$.

Thus, for every complex number $z$ with nonnegative real part,
 the function $x\mapsto1-\mathrm e^{-zx}$ is (absolutely) integrable with respect to the measure $\Pi$.

Comment: Thank you very much! May I ask what goes wrong if z doesn't have nonnegative real part?

Comment: You may: the inequality $|\mathrm e^{-tu}|\leqslant1$ with $t$ in $(0,1)$ is valid if and only if the real part of $z$ is nonnegative.

Comment: Doh. Of course.. I stared myself blind on the integral..